# Is it possible to treat fermion reheating from inflaton decay only perturbatively?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, cosmology, cosmological-inflation, non-perturbative

In case of an inflaton Lagrangian

$
\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2} (\partial_\mu \phi)^2 - \frac{1}{2}m_\phi^2 \phi^2 -h \overline{\psi} \phi \psi
$

where the inflaton field is coupled only to fermions with coupling constant $h$, and the thermal bath of standard model particles is assumed to be generated through the SM interactions subsequent to the decay of the inflaton into fermions:

1)  Would it be correct to consider only the perturbative decay $\phi \to \overline{\psi} \psi$ with decay rate $\Gamma_{\phi \to \overline{\psi} \psi} = \frac{h^2 m_\phi}{8 \pi}$ in the reheating period, or must I introduce also  a preheating phase with non-perturbative collective effects in every case?

2)  If there is any, in which regime can I neglect the non-perturbative contributions to the generation of fermions (and then the thermal bath)?

In https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9905242 and https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0003018 I found information on these non-perturbative effects, but not the clear statement whether they should be necessarily included in every case or just in some regimes.